# Examples of Galois Groups that are Algebraic Groups

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

I'm wondering when exactly a Galois group is an algebraic group. I know that they are algebraic groups when the extension is finite - so for example, $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ is an algebraic group, but $Gal(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$ is not... What are some other examples of algebraic Galois groups? And how can I further classify them and describe their properties?

Thank you :)

Comment: $Gal(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$ is the trivial group, so it is algebraic.

Comment: $Aut(k(x)/k)$ is an algebraic group (it is $PGL_2(k)$) but $Aut(k(x,y)/k)$ is not. And $Aut(\overline{k}/k)$ is an algebraic group iff it is finite iff $[\overline{k}:k]_s$ is finite. I think you should assume $K $ is the subfield fixed by $Aut(L/K)$ in your question to avoid weird undecidable cases.